# OneVsOneClassifier fails with pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scikit-learn

I have been using pandas DataFrame with scikit-learn models. Internally the pandas DataFrame is converted to numpy ndarray transparently (e.g LogisticRegression, SVC, MultinomialNB, etc).
However `sklearn.multiclass.OneVsOneClassifier` fails when given pandas DataFrame, instead it behaves properly when given numpy ndarray.
This can be reproduced with this code.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsOneClassifier

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(15), 'b': range(20, 35)})
labels = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c'] * 5)

clf = OneVsOneClassifier(LogisticRegression())
# clf = LogisticRegression()   # This works file

clf.fit(df, labels)
```

**Can someone confirm if this is a bug?**
If not point me to documentation where this is explained.

### Additional information:

I traced the root cause for this to sklearn/multiclass.py in the last line of the function [`_fit_ovo_binary`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/multiclass.py#L403)

```
return _fit_binary(estimator, X[ind[cond]], y_binary, classes=[i, j])
```

Here it assumes `X` is numpy ndarray (in reality is pandas DataFrame) and tries to use integer indexing. Which results in the exception.

Comment: scikit makes no claim to handle pandas structures, although sometimes they do happen to work.

Comment: @BrenBarn Yes I know scikit-does not claim to do so. But OneVsRestClassifier and OutputCodeClassifier (found in the same package) does not seem to throw exception. Why the inconsistent behavior?

Comment: From personal experience I tend to call `.values` to pass a np array so this works: `clf.fit(df.values, labels)`

Comment: scikit makes no guarantees of any kind about what will happen when you use a pandas structure.  It's not that it won't work; it's not that it will work.  It's that the behavior is undefined.  Any time it works, it's just coincidence.  You've essentially answered your own question by tracking down the code that causes the error: OneVsOne happens to do something that doesn't work with a DataFrame, but the other classifiers don't happen to do that.